# Pig : result of json loader empty

Tags: json, apache-pig, hue, cloudera-cdh

I'm using cdh5 quickstart vm and I have a file like this(not full here):

```
{"user_id": "kim95",
 "type": "Book",
 "title": "Modern Database Systems: The Object Model, Interoperability, and
Beyond.",
 "year": "1995",
 "publisher": "ACM Press and Addison-Wesley",
 "authors": {},
 "source": "DBLP"
}
{"user_id": "marshallo79",
 "type": "Book",
 "title": "Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Application.",
 "year": "1979",
 "publisher": "Academic Press",
 "authors": {("Albert W. Marshall"), ("Ingram Olkin")},
 "source": "DBLP"
}
```

---

and I used this script:

```js
books = load 'data/book-seded.json'
        using JsonLoader('t1:tuple(user_id:
chararray,type:chararray,title:chararray,year:chararray,publisher:chararray,source:chararray,authors:bag{T:tuple(author:chararray)})');

STORE books INTO 'book-no-seded.tsv';
```

the script works , but the generated file is empty, do you have any idea?

Comment: I also tried to adapt my script after changing data format via sed in terminal using this website : http://joshualande.com/read-write-json-apache-pig/    but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally , only this schema worked : If I add or remove a space different from this configuration then i gonna have an error( i also added "name" for tuples and specified "null" when it was empty, and changed the order between authors and source, but even without this congiguration it will still be wrong)

```
{"user_id": "kim95", "type": "Book","title": "Modern Database Systems: The Object Model, Interoperability, and Beyond.", "year": "1995", "publisher": "ACM Press and Addison-Wesley", "authors": [{"name":null"}], "source": "DBLP"}
{"user_id": "marshallo79", "type": "Book", "title": "Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Application.", "year": "1979", "publisher": "Academic Press", "authors": [{"name":"Albert W. Marshall"},{"name":"Ingram Olkin"}], "source": "DBLP"}
```

And the working script is this one :

```
books = load 'data/book-seded-workings-reduced.json'
        using JsonLoader('user_id:chararray,type:chararray,title:chararray,year:chararray,publisher:chararray,authors:{(name:chararray)},source:chararray');

STORE books INTO 'book-table.csv';  //whether .tsv or .csv
```

Answer (score 0):

try STORE books INTO 'book-no-seded.tsv' using USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.JsonStorage();

Comment: It didn't work with "USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.JsonStorage();" but only with "USING JsonStorage();"..... But the file is still empty

Comment: Finally i got four files: "success" file is empty . In "part-m-00000" i have this : " {"t1":null}"... Is it related with my answer to Romain???

Answer (score 0):

You need to bu sure that the LOAD schema is good. You can try to do a `DUMP books` to quick check.

We had to be careful with the input data and the schema when we used the Pig JsonLoader for this tutorial http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorials-ii-1-prepare-the-data-for-analysis/.

Comment: "DUMP" didn't work, I got this error : " You are a Hue admin but not a HDFS superuser (which is "hdfs")"   . So I created a hdfs user by selecting 'super user status' but even after logging as hdfs the error remains

Comment: I'm almost sure that I'm respecting pig conventions: all scripts with small changes failed except this one