# Pig flatten error

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, flatten, cloudera-cdh

I tried this script for my nested data :

```
 `books = load 'data/book-seded-workings-reduced.json'
    using JsonLoader('user_id:chararray,type:chararray,title:chararray,year:chararray,publisher:chararray,authors:{(name:chararray)},source:chararray');`
```

`group_auth = group books by title;`

`maped = foreach group_auth generate group, books.authors;`

`fil = foreach maped generate flatten(books);`
`DUMP fil;`

but I got this error : A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar

Any idea?

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve ? If you are not using any aggregation operation, why did you group "books" by title and then generated group, authors of the book and flattened it? You can use only foreach generate statement to do this.

Comment: Yoou can see my data here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976373/pig-result-of-json-loader-empty/25005513#25005513       I'm trying to generate for each title , authors linked to him but one by one... And later I would like to make query on author("name" field in my script) so I thought I had to remove the nested structure with flatten

Comment: I also tried to make such queries with hive but I'm still stucked with my serde error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149700/loading-json-file-with-serde-in-cloudera-and-how-working-with-json/25153552?noredirect=1#comment39165804_25153552                       So I'm little confused with Hive and Pig

Comment: In that case, you can remove group by clause. Try below code after load statement :
flatten_authors = foreach books generate title, FLATTEN(authors.name);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
books = load 'input.data'
    using JsonLoader('user_id:chararray,
                      type:chararray,
                      title:chararray,
                      year:chararray,
                      publisher:chararray,
                      authors:{(name:chararray)},source:chararray');

flatten_authors = foreach books generate title, FLATTEN(authors.name);

dump flatten_authors;
```

Output : (Input referred from [Loading JSON file with serde in Cloudera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149700/loading-json-file-with-serde-in-cloudera-and-how-working-with-json/25153552?noredirect=1#comment39165804_25153552))

```
(Modern Database Systems: The Object Model, Interoperability, and Beyond.,null)
(Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Application.,Albert W. Marshall)
(Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Application.,Ingram Olkin)
```

Comment: No idea. Let me try, will post my answer if am able to solve it!